# How do I diagonalize this Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, linear-algebra

I have a Hamiltonian
$$H = \frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{\omega^2 q^2}{2}+\frac{\gamma}{2}(qp + pq)$$
which I have to diagonalize, i.e., find $a$ and $a^\dagger$ as linear combinations of cannonical $p$ and $q$ such that

$$H = \frac{1}{2}(a^\dagger a + a a ^\dagger)$$

I tried writing
$$a = \alpha p + \beta q$$
and obtained the following relations

$$
\begin{align}
\mid\alpha\mid^2 &= 1\\
\mid \beta \mid^2 &= \omega^2\\
\overline{\alpha}\beta+\overline{\beta}\alpha &= 2\gamma
\end{align}
$$
where $\overline{x}$ is the complex conjugate of $x$. I haven't been able to find the transformations completely as these equations are not uniquely solvable. Can someone please help me? I would greatly appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this is right? Why is $\gamma$ absent?

Comment: @AfterShave I am sorry, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Let us redefine $p\rightarrow \omega p, q\rightarrow \frac{q}{\omega}$, so the Hamiltonian becomes

$$ H = \frac{\omega^2}{2}(p^2+q^2)+\gamma(pq+qp)=\omega^2\left[\frac{1}{2}(p^2+q^2)+\frac{\gamma}{\omega^2}(pq+qp)\right]
$$

So from now on I set $\omega=1$. Define $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(q+ip)$, the usual definition of annihilation operator. Then

$$
H=a^\dagger a+\frac12 + i\gamma [ a^2-(a^\dagger)^2]
$$

We look for new operators $b=u a + v a^\dagger$, such that

$$ H=Eb^\dagger b +c  = E(u^* a^\dagger + v^* a)(ua+va^\dagger)
=E(|u|^2 a^\dagger a + |v|^2 a a^\dagger + u^*v (a^\dagger)^2 + uv^* a^2)+c
$$

Here we also allow an additive constant $c$.

In addition, we want to make sure $[b,b^\dagger]=1$, so $|u|^2-|v|^2=1$ (you don't seem to have the analog of this equation in your solution). So let us write $v=-iw$, and assume $u$ and $w$ are real, then

$$ H
=E\Big((|u|^2+|w|^2) a^\dagger a + |w|^2 + iuw (a^2-(a^\dagger)^2) \Big)+c
$$

Thus we have

$$ \frac{uw}{u^2+w^2}=\gamma, u^2-w^2=1, Ew^2+c=\frac12$$

Write $u=\cosh x, w=\sinh x$, then $\tanh x = 2\gamma$, so $x=\tanh^{-1} 2\gamma$. Then from $E(|u|^2+|w|^2)=1$ we get $E=\frac{1}{\cosh 2x}$, which also gives $c$.

Comment: Wait why can we write H = Eb^\daggerb? I wanted it in the form 1/2(a^\dagger a + a a^\dagger).

Comment: If you could write it as $\frac12 (a^\dagger a+a a^\dagger)$, then the eigenvalues are the same as a standard harmonic oscillator, if $a$ satisfies canonical commutation relation. It shouldn't be the case. Here $H=Eb^\dagger b + \text{const}$ does not rely on any such additional assumptions.

Comment: a and a^\dagger aren't necessarily the creation and annihilation operators for the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: I defined $a$ and $a^\dagger$ in the standard way, and the $b$ and $b^\dagger$ are the actual annihilation and creation operators that diagonalize the Hamiltonian, and they should satisfy the commutation relation if you want them to be useful.

Comment: Basically, you are looking for $b$ and $b^\dagger$ (you called them $a$ and $a^\dagger$) in which the Hamiltonian takes the simple form. But only when $[b,b^\dagger]=1$, you can conclude that the eigenvalue of the operator $\frac12(b^\dagger b+b b^\dagger)$ is $n+\frac12$ where $n=0,1,2,\cdots$. This is likely the condition you missed.

Comment: So can we impose the condition $[b, b^\dagger]=1$?

Comment: You can, and you should. I've shown how to do this in the answer already, although it is slightly different from what you did, but should give the same result.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm stupid and I thought that you could impose [a, a^\dagger] only when we have the Harmonic oscillator? Also how would one find the ground state wavefunction and energy from this?

Comment: The point is that you want to make changes of variables to transform the problem into a "harmonic oscillator", which has the form $H=E b^\dagger b + \text{constant}, [b,b^\dagger]=1$, and then you can solve. It doesn't matter where $b$ comes from. As long as it satisfies the commutation relation, you can think of as some sort of harmonic oscillator. The ground state $|0\rangle$ is found by $b|0\rangle=0$. You may find it useful to review the algebraic derivation of the solution of a harmonic oscillator.

Answer (score 1):

Taking $Q = \omega q$, $\gamma' = \frac{\gamma}{\omega}$ (real number) you get
$$
H(p, Q) = \frac{1}{2} p^2 + \frac{1}{2} Q^2 + \frac{\gamma'}{2}(Qp + pQ)
$$
Doing as you did, $a = \alpha p + \beta Q$, we get
$$
a a^\dagger + a^\dagger a = 2|\alpha|^2 p^2 + 2|\beta|^2 Q^2 + (\alpha \bar{\beta} + \bar{\alpha} \beta)pQ + (\alpha \bar{\beta} + \bar{\alpha} \beta)Qp
$$
you get:
$$\begin{align*}
|\alpha|^2 &= \frac{1}{2} \\
|\beta|^2 &= \frac{1}{2} \\
\alpha \bar{\beta} + \bar{\alpha} \beta &= \gamma'
\end{align*}
$$
Which is kinda similar to what you had, just different values and all, but it remains a problem to solve. Notice that if theres some relative phase between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, say, $\alpha = r_\alpha e^{i \phi_{\alpha}}$ and $\beta = r_\beta e^{i \phi_{\beta}}$, it doesn't matter if you decide, instead, to "factor out" the pure phase of $\alpha$ (pure phase doesn't do anything to kets in the end, probability-wise) and let now **$\alpha$ be a real number** and do the rest of the math with $\beta$, that is, $\alpha$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $\text{Re}(\beta) = \frac{\gamma'}{\sqrt{2}}$ (see last eq.) and plugging $\beta = \frac{\gamma'}{\sqrt{2}} + ix$ into the second equation, you get:
$$
\frac{1}{2} = \frac{\gamma'}{2} + x^2 \Longrightarrow x = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{1 - \gamma'}
$$
and I just hope your $\gamma'$ isn't larger than $1$...

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting something similar. How do I go about finding the ground state from this?

Comment: Actually finding the wavefunction? I guess you'll have to solve the Schrödinger equation using $H\psi = E\psi$, $p \to -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial q}$ and all... unless you could somehow "factor" into some new variables that would give a simple harmonic oscillator on these new variables...

Comment: Yeah the question actually wants me to find the ground state wavefunction. I guess I have to impose the condition $[a, a^\dagger] = 1$ so that I can get the wavefunction?